# How without IP address to link other file?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I've created hyperlink to open other page, but I want without  IP address to link the page.How should I need edit in my code?

My coding show in the below:

```
<a href='http://192.168.1.100/asisto_new/index.php'>Back <a/>
```

Is possible using other methods without http://192.168.1.100 to open index.php file?

Comment: First you write "without protocol", but then it seems that you want to omit the IP address as well - which one is it? If the linking page is located at the same IP address, you can just use relative paths to `asisto_new/index.php`. What that would look like depends on where the linking page is located.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've edited protocol to IP address